# Flutter AdMob: "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement"

Tags: flutter, admob

I'm using AdMob on Flutter to display Rewarded ads.
Upon watching the test ad and delivering the reward to the user, I receive the following error:

```html
[assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}>

[ProcessSuspension] 0x121070180 - ProcessAssertion::acquireSync Failed to acquire RBS assertion 'WebProcess Suspended Assertion' for process with PID=62590, error: Error Domain=RBSServiceErrorDomain Code=1 "target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=target is not running or doesn't have entitlement com.apple.runningboard.assertions.webkit}
Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service
```

**Here's my info.plist:**

```html
    <key>GADApplicationIdentifier</key>
    <string>ca-app-pub-############~#########</string>
  
  <key>SKAdNetworkItems</key>
    <array>
    // a long dictionary I copied from the documentation
  </array>
```

I looked around, but couldn't find any solutions for this error,
followed every step in the official documentation.

Any ideas what went wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is due to the lack of App permissions to load arbitrary content into a webkit view in order to render the ad.

Try adding this to your Info.plist:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsForMedia</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```